# How can I redirect the contents of a folder to other domain?

Tags: iis-7.5, php5

We have moved our website to wordpress but we do rely on several folders and we already have link and images pointing to the old locations.

for example:

```
http://domain.com/t/image_001.png
```

but I do not want to add all images again to the new web location, I would rather set a sub domain and keep them in the same place

How can I redirect

`http://domain.com/t/*.*` to `http://t.domain.com/*.*`?

something I need to do in `php.ini` file? or it's a website configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's an **IIS Server** (as the tag specifies) you have 2 options:

create the folder you want in the new site and add a `web.config` file with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://t.domain.com" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

or, if you want to use the GUI

Select the folder, and open HTTP Redirect under "IIS"

[image]

and set the new domain

[image]

Comment: Blegh, I completely missed that :)

Comment: How do I keep the querystring values?